# How do I make a php code so my category is able to be viewed by certian user ranks

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php code. I want to know if its possible to make an if statement so it can only be viewed by the user with a user level of 1. I tried an if statement but I get an Unexpected T_STRING my database had this http://prntscr.com/glmqi cat_mod is for the if statement because it's a moderator topic.

```
<?php





$sql = "SELECT
        cat_id,
        cat_name,
        cat_description
    FROM
        categories
    WHERE
        cat_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$result)
{
echo 'The category could not be displayed, please try again later.' .   mysql_error();
}
else
{
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    echo 'This category does not exist.';
}
else
{
    //display category data
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo '

<h3>You are currently in this section: <u>' . $row['cat_name'] . '<u/></h3>
</div>
  <div class="container_oro2" style="overflow: hidden;">
  Users currently viewing this section:
  </div><div class="header">
    <h3 class="header_title">Topics in this section</h3>
    <div class="header_topics">Hits</div>
    <div class="header_replies">Replies</div>
    <div class="header_action">Last Action</div>
</div><table class="container">';
    }

    //do a query for the topics
    $sql = "SELECT  
                topics.topic_id,
                topics.topic_subject,
                topics.topic_date,
                topics.topic_cat,
                topics.topic_by,
                topics.view,
                topics.reply,
                users.user_id,
                users.user_name
            FROM
                topics

            LEFT JOIN
                    users
                ON
                    topics.topic_by = users.user_id             
            WHERE
                topic_cat = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if(!$result)
    {
        echo 'The topics could not be displayed, please try again later.';
    }
    else
    {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
        {
            echo 'There are no topics in this section yet.';
        }
        else
        {
            //prepare the table



            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {               
                echo '




                <tr class="altcolor_2">';

            echo '<td class="title">';
            echo '  <table>';
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td class="title_icon_small">
                            <img src="http://www.naruto-boards.com/images/forum/topic_old.gif" alt="" />                            </td>
                        <td class="title_icon_small">
                            <img src="http://www.naruto-boards.com/images/forum/topic_sticky.gif" alt="" />                             </td>
                        <td class="title_title">';
                            echo '<h4 class="inline"><a href="/index.php?area=topic&id=' . $row['topic_id'] . '">' . $row['topic_subject'] . '</a>   ';                                          echo '<img class="pages" src="http://naruto-boards.com/images/forum/topic_paging.gif"  alt="" /> </h4> ';
                            echo'<span>Started on ';  echo date(" F j, Y, g:i A", strtotime($row['topic_date'])); echo' by <a  href="/profile/kross/" class="profilelink"></a></span>';
                        echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                echo '</table>';

            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td class="info1">' . $row['view'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td class="info1">' . $row['reply'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td class="info2">
                <div>';
                    echo'Date: ';echo date(" F j, Y, g:i A", strtotime($row['topic_date']));echo'<br />';
                    echo 'By: <a href="/profile/igi33/"  class="profilelink"></a>';

                echo '</div>';
            echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr class="spacer"><td colspan="4"></td></tr>


';








            }
        }
    }
}
}


?>
```

Comment: You need to do more due-diligence before asking this question. To begin with, your code is almost entirely unformatted and hard to understand. Secondly, you haven't found the area of your problem; just handed us code and hope we can find it. Be precise about what you tried, the input you gave and the error messages/output you got.

Comment: Note that although you’re using `mysql_real_escape_string` your code is still vulnerable to SQL injections as you’re not using it properly. `mysql_real_escape_string` is intended to be used for data that is to be used in MySQL strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an `if` at the end of the `$sql`, before the `$result = ....`

```
if ($user_level != 1) { $sql .=  " AND `cat_mod` = 0";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a database call to grab the `cat_mod` and compare it against your users level (preferably you will have your users level at the very start of your script.) and compare those two values against each other. Something along the lines of this.

```
<?php
$sql = "select name, level 
        FROM users 
        WHERE id = $userId 
        AND name = $userName"; // You have to be storing a cookie or something so that we know the user is logged in and is who they say they are.
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
```

You can now conditionally append to your SQL statement, checking if the user is allowed to see the mod categories.

```
$sql = "SELECT
    cat_id,
    cat_name,
    cat_description
FROM
    categories
WHERE
    cat_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

if ($user["level"] == 0) {
    $sql .= " AND cat_mod = 0";
}
```

Note that neither of my listed SQL calls are actually secure.

Comment: I get this Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /www/zzl.org/l/u/x/luxurious/htdocs/category.php on line 113

Comment: Assuming you just copy/pasted the code I gave you, the table names for the user and the variables in which to grab that information are most likely the cause of the issue. Can you echo the $sql variable and plug that into PHPMyAdmin or something similar? That should help you figuring out why the SQL call failed.